# Delete Excel rows programmatically using Java

Tags: java, excel

Finding last column cell values. if cell value is "Not Valid" or "Not Applicable", delete the entire row.

The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class Column
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Excel1.xlsx"));
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Retail-All");

            Workbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook();
            wb2 = wb;

            Row row;
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            int getLastCell=row.getLastCellNum()-1;
            int lastIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++)
            {
                row=sheet.getRow(i);
                if(row.getCell(getLastCell)!=null && (row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not valid) || row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Applicable")))
                {
                    sheet.removeRow(row);
                    //sheet.shiftRows(i, lastIndex, -1);
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/shiftRows.xlsx");
            wb2.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, using row.setZeroHeight(true); method I can able to hide the rows.

With the above code, using sheet.removeRow(row); method I can able to empty all the cells in that particular row.

I found some code in net, but none of them are deleting the rows permanently.My requirement is to delete the rows permanently. How to code to meet my requirement?

Comment: If the spredsheet is not that big you can clear the row you want to delete and then shift back one position the row below... Not the optimal but an option.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a VBA macro would be more helpful in this situation? VBA macros can be embedded into your spreadsheet, so running them could be a lot easier.

Here is a good place to get started with VBA:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Java is good but in this case I think a VBA macro would be much easier and more efficient.

Comment: If you're working with Excel a lot it's not a bad idea to pick it up, it's very easy to learn. Either way it seems that Ganesh has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
 SVTableModel model = new SVTableModel(sheet);
 int lastIndex = model.getRowCount();
 for (int i=1; i<=lastIndex; i++)
   {
  row=sheet.getRow(i);
  if((row.getCell(getLastCell)!=null) && (row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not valid") ||  row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Applicable")))
  {
      row.setZeroHeight(true);
      sheet.removeRow(row);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sheet.removeRow(row);` you can use the `shiftRows(int startRow, int endRow, int n)` instruction, that seems you have tried, that shifts rows between startRow and endRow n number of rows.

In your case it will be

```
// ... code before    ...
for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++)
        {
          row=sheet.getRow(i);
          if(row.getCell(getLastCell)!=null && (row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not valid") || row.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Applicable")))
              {
               // This should shift up by 1 row all the rows below
               sheet.shiftRows(i+1, lastIndex, -1);
               i--; // Since you move row at i+1 to i you have to recompute the i-th row
            }
        }
// ... code after ...
```

Check [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) for more information

Comment: @JavaDeveloper In the code you posted,you didn't set properly the values to shift the row. In fact you are shift all the rows including the one you want to delete up by one, instead i'm moving up by 1 all the row below the one you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. My last cell value is Mismatched ot 
    Matched. Set as per ur excel.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DeleteAllRecord {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        File src= new File("testdata\\OSBC.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet data= workbook.getSheet("TestData");  
        int length=data.getLastRowNum();
        XSSFSheet data1;
        Row row1;
        for(int i=1;i<=length;i++){

            String testCaseNo=data.getRow(i).getCell(4).toString();
            System.out.println("The Testcase no "+testCaseNo);
            data1= workbook.getSheet(testCaseNo);
            row1 = data1.getRow(2);
            int getLastCell=row1.getLastCellNum()-1;
            System.out.println("The last cell is "+getLastCell);
            int lastIndex = data1.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("The last row is "+lastIndex);
            String str1= row1.getCell(getLastCell).toString();
            System.out.println("The valu1 is "+ str1);
            for (int j=0; j<lastIndex-1; j++)
            {

                String str=data1.getRow(j+2).getCell(getLastCell).toString();
                row1=data1.getRow(j+2);
                System.out.println("print " + (j+2) +str);

                if(row1.getCell(getLastCell)!=null &&
(row1.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MATCHED")||
row1.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MISMATCHED")|| 
row1.getCell(getLastCell).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))){

data1.removeRow(row1);
                    System.out.println("print " + (j+2)+ " " +str);

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Null");
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("testdata\\delete.xlsx");
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("File deleted");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("No Data Exists to delete");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This code is for deleting all the records in the different sheet. Just pass the value of the sheet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Posting long code as answer is fine but it's important that you explain what exactly you changed in OP's code to make it work