# How can I delete lines of a big .xlsx file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a 1 million line .xlsx file , the data is a sensor monitoring data . Now I want to use poi traversing row while deleting some unwanted rows of data, how can I do ? Can SXSSF work ? Who can provide me the example codes.thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to traverse, how to delete or how to recognize unwanted rows?

Comment: Thank you for your attention~!  I want to delete some unwanted rows of my .xlsx file while traversalling the  excel row by row, the excel have 1 million rows.You understand?

Comment: I do understand what you said - but are you asking for code for all three parts or are you just stuck on the delete part?

Comment: I  want the  code of deleting rows using POI EventModel, because  UserModel  requires the file into memory all at once, which throw an exception of out of memory in eclipse. But I do not know how to use the EventModel to do the job of deleting rows.

Comment: Have you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995796/delete-excel-rows-programatically-using-java

Comment: Or this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf

Comment: this two questions are solutions of processing 97-2003 excel(.xls) using HSSF

Comment: The first one is reading in an XSLX

Comment: @dorbodwolf  please post solution for this if you cracked it with java code

Comment: finally I found solution of this kind problem by using Python, before processing I save the .xlsx file as .csv and read csv in Python, for data analysis, I donnot think Java is the best solution now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will promt you for a line number... and then delete it

```
 Sub Makro1()
    '
    ' Makro1 Makro
    '
    myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
        Rows(myValue).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End Sub
```

Comment: That is not Java, which the OP is asking for

Comment: @dorbodwolf please post solution for this if you cracked it with java code

Comment: @user2572801 finally I found solution of this kind problem by using Python, before processing I save the .xlsx file as .csv and read  csv in Python, for data analysis, I donnot think Java is the best solution now. Good luck!